# Why do we subtract the voltage of the resistor from the emf voltage to find the terminal voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I attached an image of a question from homework.
I calculated the current in step 1) and then I calculated the voltage of the resistor. But why do I need to subtract that voltage from the emf voltage in order to get the terminal voltage?

[image]

I am new to the Physics Stack Exchange so please let me know if I cannot ask questions like this on here before downvoting.

Comment: You didn't just use $V=IR$ for the volt meter?

Comment: That would yield a different answer of 1.49779... so why is that? is it still right?

Comment: I think you're making a mistake... $\left (4.99918\times10^{-4}\ \rm A\right)\left (3000\ \Omega\right)=1.49975\ \rm V$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Kirchoff's rule for voltage drops around the circuit
$$\epsilon-v_m-v_r=0$$
where "m" and "r" represent the voltmeter and internal resistance respectively.

So you could use the given EMF and the voltage across the resistor, given by $v_r=IR_r$, so that
$$v_m=\epsilon-IR_r$$
and this is why your method works.

---

However, it's much easier just to do
$$v_m=IR_m$$

Both ways are self-consistent because $$\epsilon=I(R_m+R_r)$$
so
$$v_m=\epsilon-IR_r=I(R_m+R_r)-IR_r=IR_m$$